# River rock shower floor grout cracking

Tags: shower, floor, epoxy, rock

Have river rock shower floor in the master bath. About a year ago noticed some cracks in the grout around the rocks. I contacted the home manufacturer and they advised to regrout over the existing grout and to reseal. Let the floor dry for a week and followed their instructions. Again have cracks around some of the rocks. I do not want to have to tear out the whole floor. Looking on line I have seen recommendations to use epoxy grout. I have also thought about putting a thin 1/4" layer of epoxy mixed with some thing to give it some texture. Also wondering how to set up the drain so the epoxy does not clog it. Any suggestions.

Comment: Redoing grout means removing old grout that has cracks.  For blocking the drain, remove the cover and stuff something soft inside(that is headed for the garbage).

Comment: Tape off the drain when you epoxy?